# Form validation 'dimensions' throws BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I'm developing a web application in Laravel 5.2.22 and I'm running into a problem with form validation.

I want to validate the dimensions of user uploaded avatars with the 'dimensions' validation rule. This is how I configured it in my `rules()` array: `'profile_image' => 'image|dimensions:min_width=360,min_height=360'`. When I submit the form though, I get this error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Validator.php line 2950:
Method [validateDimensions] does not exist.
in Validator.php line 2950
at Validator->__call('validateDimensions', array('profile_image', 'avatar.jpg', array('min_width=360', 'min_height=360'), object(Validator))) in Validator.php line 416
at Validator->validateDimensions('profile_image', 'avatar.jpg', array('min_width=360', 'min_height=360'), object(Validator)) in Validator.php line 416
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why @Derp deleted their post, but they're exactly right.

You're running `5.2.2` which does not have the `dimensions` validation rule. That was introduced in version `5.2.32` on `2016-05-17`

Simply upgrade your Laravel installation.

Also, as Laravel 5.2 is not the LTS version, be aware changes happen all the time, so you should consider updating *every day*.

[Here's a changelog](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/CHANGELOG.md) you can watch so you can compare new features of new minor releases.

Comment: Ahh I see! Thank you so much. This totally worked :) Cheers!